# How to color a WMS layer using database value

Tags: wms

I have a transparent WMS layer of polygons. It is a map of a city and i want to color the map according to crime rate. Rate values are obtained from database. I dont know how to select a single polygon from that layer and color it according to the rate. Please help. Am trying to implement it using GeoServer and Openlayers and this is a client side operation

[image]

This is my map and i want a output like shown below

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE, if you would like to get an answer, you need to indicate what WMS server you are using, what Client you are using, whether you want to color it on the server or the Client. Please edit your question and the tags to reflect these items.